# how to determine the browser version and IP address of logged in user using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, webclient

Morning

I have these functions below using "navigator" to retrieve various information about the operating system browser and device type. I would like to know I can get the IP address ,version of the browser and I would like to know if its possible to get the device type whether its a desktop , phone or tablet . This is what I have so far

```
function detectmob() {
    //alert(BrowserDetect.browser);
    var os = navigator.platform ; 
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)

    ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function detectBroswer() {
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
        alert('Opera');
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
        alert('Chrome');
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
        alert('Safari');
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        alert('Firefox');
    }
    else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) //IF IE > 10
    {
        alert('IE');
    }
    else {
        alert('unknown');
    }
}
```

Comment: With features like Continuum, how did you want to define Phone/Tablet/Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the IP address of logged in user using javascript,
but here is what I've found on how you could check what version of browser user is using.

```js
navigator.sayswho = (function(){
  var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem,
      M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];

  if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
    tem =  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return "IE " + (tem[1] || "");
  }

  if(M[1] === "Chrome") {
    tem = ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
    if(tem != null) 
      return tem.slice(1).join(" ").replace("OPR", "OPERA");
  }

  M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];

  if( (tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) 

    M.splice(1, 1, tem[1] );

  return M.join(" ");
})();

alert(navigator.sayswho)
```

Comment: glad it helps you :)